# COUNT() over result of Except

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregation

I have a query like:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    ...
WHERE
    ...
    AND eventtype IN (2000120, 2000121, 2000122, 2000123, 2000130)

EXCEPT

SELECT
    id
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    ...
WHERE
    ...
    AND eventtype IN (2000123,2000130,2000134,2000135)
```

Note that the queries are both identical except the last where-clause.

I would now like to count the number of records returned by this above query.

How to?

Many thanks

Comment: In queries different only predicate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How do you mean that?

Comment: Do you also need to retrieve the result set as well?

Comment: No, only the count of the result. But the solution provided by JW is nice. Except that I have to select the date and other criteria twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `COUNT` and wrap it inside a `SUBQUERY`

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        INNER JOIN...
        WHERE...
                AND eventtype IN ( 2000120, 2000121, 2000122, 2000123, 2000130 )
        EXCEPT
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        INNER JOIN...
        WHERE...
                AND eventtype IN ( 2000123, 2000130, 2000134, 2000135 )
        ) s
```

Comment: Thanks for your very fast reply. This works... One resulting question: As both sub-SELECTs are exactly the same (except the eventtype)... can the query be optimized? I further have for example the WHERE-clause (`eventtime BETWEEN '2013-02-08 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-08 23:59:59'`) in both queries

Answer (score 1):

you just need the first query for what you want, you don't have to include the 2000130 value if you don't need it and so the other values that you don't want to be shown in you query.

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    ...
WHERE
    ...
    AND eventtype IN (2000120, 2000121, 2000122, 2000123)
```

If you need to exclude some values from the some query you can use

```
    AND eventtype NOT IN (2000130)
```

But not both at once. And to count just a regular use `SELECT COUNT(id)` or a subquery if you want.

Comment: Nice try. But this does actually not work because the query is more complex. In fact, 'id' is reduced to one `DISTINCT` value whereas more values would exist. With your variant, I'm excluding values which aren't in there anyway. I need to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use EXISTS with INTERSECT sub-query

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN ...
WHERE ... AND eventtype IN (2000120, 2000121, 2000122, 2000123, 2000130)
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table1 t2 INNER JOIN ...
WHERE ... AND eventtype IN (2000123, 2000130, 2000134, 2000135)
AND EXISTS (SELECT t1.ID 
            INTERSECT
            SELECT t2.ID))
```